# Java execute exe with multi write/read on stdin stdout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, process, stdout, stdin

I have a exe program which receive input on stdin and return on stdout. This application takes time to start. So I don't want to start a new Process every time I have a request.

For the moment I use

```
Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(prg + " " + arg);
```

I write like that:

```
PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(cmd.getOutputStream());
pWriter.println("input");
pWriter.flush();
```

And to be able to read I have to close my pWriter

```
pWriter.close();
```

After I can read the output.

My problem is I cannot open again pWriter. And if I don't close, it will not be able to read.

Any idea to solve my problem?

Have a nice day

Comment: The only reason for having to close the writer is because that's how the process is implemented. There's little you can do about that.

Comment: Could you explain me with more details please?

Comment: Your process reads the data from `stdin` until it reaches end-of-stream. You cannot signal an end-of-stream to the process without closing your writer at the Java end.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but doesn't imply his want to open the stream again that he wants to send additional data? Which would mean that the process is indeed able to handle more data?

Comment: @Ingo, exactly, my program is able to receive additional data.

Comment: @Ingo OP is either misrepresenting his problem, or the process does not output anything until it has exhausted its `stdin`. In either case there is nothing more to add based on OP's description.

Comment: @user2783158 Do you need the output of the process to compute further data you want to send it?

Comment: I do need it, input-output input-output without recreat the new process everytime.

Comment: Do you have an idea ??